# Why am I unable to load a Perl library when using the `do` function?

Tags: perl, subroutine

I'm new to Perl, and I'm updating an old Perl website. Every `.pl` file seems to have this line at the top:

```
do "func.inc";
```

So I figured I could use this file to tag on a subroutine for global use.

#### func.inc

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
sub foobar
{
    return "Hello world";
}
```

#### index.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
do "func.inc";
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print foobar();
```

However, I get this error:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::foobar called at /path/to/index.pl line 4.
```

Both files are in the same directory, and there's tones of subs in `func.inc` already which are used throughout the website. However, the script works in the Linux production environment, but does not work for my Windows 7 dev environment (I'm using ActivePerl).

### Update:

It looks like the file is not being included; the sub works if the file is included using an absolute path...

```
do "C:/path/to/func.inc";
```

... so it looks like relative paths don't work for my local dev environment, but they work in the production environment through. But this is no good for me, because the absolute path on my dev machine will not work for the live server.

How do I get `do` to work using a relative path on my Windows 7 dev machine?

### Update 2:

I was using the Perl `-T` switch. Unfortunately this removes "." from @INC, and so stops us from using relative paths for `do`. I removed this switch and the old code is working now. I'm aware that this is not good practice, but unfortunately I'm working with old code, so it seems that I have no choice.

Comment: Works for me. Maybe you have a syntax error in the actual included file? Why not use packages?

Comment: @Lukáš Looks like my environment does not support relative paths.

Comment: Relative paths should work fine if the file is in @INC. It's not a problem with your system. Packages aren't going to solve this, either.

Comment: Also, the worst way to learn Perl is by reading random code that somebody left you. You pick up all of their bad habits and misunderstandings.

Comment: @brian Excellent advice! About 10 years ago I learnt PHP through someone else's bad code, and it took me a long time to undo. Thankfully I learnt C++ some time ago, and this has helped to undo a lot of bad practices I picked up. Unfortunately my job right now requires me to "hack" this Perl script until it works. And since I'm a Perl beginner and I value my job, it wouldn't be prudent to start re-factoring the entire website ;-)

Comment: Update 2 is incorrect. I was in the middle of writing an answer to your other question that would have explained what was going on, but you deleted it.

Comment: Removing -T was rash. You've just disabled important security protection.

Comment: @gbacon I'm very sorry to have interrupted your answer. Although I think when working with old [smelly] code you need to allow a certain amount of leeway with regards to strictness. If I were writing new Perl code I would **absolutely** use the `-T` switch.

Comment: You're charging ahead based on incorrect assumptions. `-T` is not a matter of strictness: it's a guardrail that stops you plunging over a cliff. You've admitted that you're a beginner, so slow down and listen to the valuable advice from us seasoned veterans!

Comment: @gbacon Perhaps I haven't explained myself very well. I really do appreciate the time you're spending to help me, and I believe that you have my best interests at heart, so **thank you** - I really mean that. However, unfortunately I will not be using `-T` in this case, since I am working with very old code that I know nothing about. I feel that it would be very unwise of me to try and refactor the entire website for it to work with `-T`. The website is obsolete and I'm not allowed to spend too much time fixing it. But really, thanks for your advice - please don't take this personally!

Comment: It seems I'm the one who's been making unwarranted assumptions, and for that I apologize. I hope you'll pardon my alarm: I feared you were about to shoot your foot off. This huge flaw in the production site presents you with a fantastic opportunity. This is a critical security problem. Make people in your organization aware of this problem and then take the lead on cleaning it up. Security is not a problem for beginners, so you need to read up and become an expert quickly. We're here to help.

Comment: @gbacon Great, thanks for understanding. If we decide to keep the old Perl site then it'll probably become my pet project. If so, I will dedicate some time to freshen up the old code, and rest assured I'll be turning that `-T` switch back on!

Comment: +1 for the amount of civility in this thread.

Comment: I agree with Ether, civility++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making sure the path is correct, use:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
require("func.inc");
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"; 
print foobar();
```

Comment: I was using the `-T` switch - doh! You're right though, the code should be using `require` as this checks that Perl can actually find the file instead of failing silently.

Comment: Please, in every question, show us the real code that shows the problem. You have to show us exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Read the docs to see how `do` lets you know about failure. `-T` is a great safety mechanism. Even if you think you know what you're doing, you shouldn't disable it.

Comment: @brian I do apologise; being a new to Perl I did not realise it was important to describe exactly how I was running the script. I will make sure to think more carefully about this sort of stuff in future.

Comment: @gbacon Thanks for the tip. However, I need my development environment to match the production environment, and since the production environment does not use `-T`, then it looks like I cannot (unless I want to spend my entire weekend fixing the old smelly code, which I don't). For any new code I write, or any new deployments I absolutely assure you that I will use `-T`! :)

Comment: When switching `require` (yes, the better choice, or, better still, go with `use`) for `do` in the production environment, be prepared for breakage in case some code is inadvertently depending on silent failure.

Answer (score 6):

The [perlfunc documentation for `do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) reads

> - **do EXPR**
>     Uses the value of `EXPR` as a filename and executes the contents of the file as a Perl script.
>
>   ```
>   do 'stat.pl';
>   ```
>
>   is just like
>
>   ```
>   eval `cat stat.pl`;
>   ```
>
>   except that it's more efficient and concise, keeps track of the current filename for error messages, searches the `@INC` directories, and updates `%INC` if the file is found.

So to see all this in action, say `C:\Cygwin\tmp\mylib\func.inc` looks like

```
sub hello {
  print "Hello, world!\n";
}

1;
```

and we make use of it in the following program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

# your code may have unshift @INC, ...
use lib "C:/Cygwin/tmp/mylib";

my $func = "func.inc";

do $func;

# Now we can just call it. Note that with strict subs enabled,
# we have to use parentheses. We could also predeclare with
# use subs qw/ hello /; 
hello();

# do places func.inc's location in %INC
if ($INC{$func}) {
  print "$0: $func found at $INC{$func}\n";
}
else {
  die "$0: $func missing from %INC!";
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello, world!
./prog: func.inc found at C:/Cygwin/tmp/mylib/func.inc
```

As you've observed, `do` ain't always no crystal stair, which the `do` documentation explains:

> If `do` cannot read the file, it returns `undef` and sets `$!` to the error. If do can read the file but cannot compile it, it returns `undef` and sets an error message in `$@`. If the file is successfully compiled, `do` returns the value of the last expression evaluated.

To check all these cases, we can no longer use simply `do "func.inc"` but

```
unless (defined do $func) {
  my $error = $! || $@;
  die "$0: do $func: $error";
}
```

Explanations for each case are below.

#### `do` cannot read the file

If we rename `func.inc` to `nope.inc` and rerun the program, we get

```
./prog: do func.inc: No such file or directory at ./prog line 12.
```

#### `do` can read the file but cannot compile it

Rename `nope.inc` back to `func.inc` and delete the closing curly brace in `hello` to make it look like

```
sub hello {
  print "Hello, world!\n";

1;
```

Running the program now, we get

```
./prog: do func.inc: Missing right curly or square bracket at C:/Cygwin/tmp/mylib/func.inc line 4, at end of line
syntax error at C:/Cygwin/tmp/mylib/func.inc line 4, at EOF
```

#### `do` can read the file and compile it, but it does not return a true value.

Delete the `1;` at the end of `func.inc` to make it

```
sub hello {
  print "Hello, world!\n";
}
```

Now the output is

```
./prog: do func.inc:  at ./prog line 13.
```

So without a return value, success resembles failure. We could complicate the code that checks the result of `do`, but the better choice is to always return a true value at the end of Perl libraries and modules.

Note that the program runs correctly even with taint checking (`-T`) enabled. Try it and see! Be sure to read [Taint mode and `@INC` in perlsec](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Taint-mode-and-%40INC).

Comment: Hmm, I don't know what to say... When I remove `-T`, it works. When I add `-T` back it complains that the file does not exist. Maybe this is a Windows 7/ActivePerl problem?

Comment: See the docs linked at the end of my answer: "When the taint mode (-T) is in effect, the '.' directory is removed from @INC, and the environment variables PERL5LIB and PERLLIB are ignored by Perl." Did you try running the program from my answer with and without `-T`?

Comment: Rather than dropping `-T`, would it be better to use `-T -I.`? Or does this defeat the purpose?

Comment: Notice that my code uses `use lib "/absolute/path/to/lib";`. Relative paths such as `"."` are unsafe because they could allow your code to be tricked into running arbitrary code. The linked "Taint mode and `@INC`" section recommends `perl -T -Mlib=/foo program`. Running this way in development allows you to supply a slightly different environment without having to change the production code until you're ready.

Answer (score 3):

You use the subroutine the same way that you'd use any other subroutine. It doesn't matter that you loaded it with `do`. However, you shouldn't use `do` for that. Check out the "Packages" chapter in [Intermediate Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596102067) for a detailed explanation of loading subroutines from other files. In short, use [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) instead.

See the documentation for [do](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html). You need to have *func.inc* (which you can also just call *func.pl* since *pl* is "perl library") in one of the directories where Perl will look for libraries. That might be different than the directory that has *index.pl*. Put *func.inc* in `@INC` somewhere, or add its directory to `@INC`. `do` also doesn't die if it can't load the file, so it doesn't tell you that it failed. That's why you shouldn't use `do` to load libraries. :)

Comment: Ah, I see. I will use packages for anything I implement myself, but I'm not sure it'd be wise to re-implement this existing system using packages, since I'm a Perl beginner.

Comment: This has nothing to do with packages. You're a bit behind the curve, so you might want to catch up by reading _Learning Perl_ and _Intermediate Perl_. I explain all of this stuff in great detail.

Comment: @brian Are these the correct links? http://learn.perl.org/ and http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596102067

Comment: Well, those are the titles of my books. Buy them wherever you like. :) The learn.perl.org is not the website for my book.

Comment: @brian Thanks for clearing that up, I just wanted to make sure. And it's just as well I asked because I was going to assume that website was yours! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would first check if the file was actually loaded, the [documentation for `do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) mentions that it updates `%INC` if the file was found. There is also more information in the documentation.

Comment: You don't want to check %INC. Don't use do. Use require instead.

Comment: @brian Thanks, I will make sure I avoid `do` for any new code I write!

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have func.inc in the correct path.

```
do "func.inc"
```

means you are saying func.inc is in the same path as your perl script. check the correct path and then do this

```
do "/path/func.inc"
```